# Cross compiling - V8 build for android on mac

Tags: android, macos, android-ndk, cross-compiling, v8

There are some questions about this issue. But the answers are not helpful. I try to generate D8 for android. [The v8 guide](https://github.com/v8/v8/wiki/Building-with-Gyp) says that gyp is deprecated. My steps are here :

1. git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git

   2. export PATH='pwd'/depot_tools:"$PATH"
   3. Download ndk-r14b
   4. fetch v8
   5. cd v8
   6. echo "target_os = ['android']" >> ../.gclient && gclient sync --nohooks
   7. tools/dev/v8gen.py arm.release
   8. gn gen out.gn/arm.release --args='android_ndk_root="/path/android-ndk-r14b" android_ndk_version="r14" v8_static_library=true android_sdk_root="/path/android-sdk-r25"  target_os = "android" target_cpu = "arm" v8_target_cpu = "arm" is_component_build = false'
   9. ninja -C out.gn/arm.release d8

Compilation throws some errors.

```
In file included from ../../third_party/icu/source/common/unicode/unistr.h:33:0,
                 from ../../third_party/icu/source/common/unicode/locid.h:36,
                 from ../../third_party/icu/source/i18n/unicode/dcfmtsym.h:36,
                 from ../../third_party/icu/source/i18n/unicode/decimfmt.h:38,
                 from ../../third_party/icu/source/i18n/digitlst.h:32,
                 from ../../third_party/icu/source/i18n/visibledigits.cpp:18:
../../third_party/icu/source/common/unicode/std_string.h:35:18: fatal error: string: No such file or directory
 #include <string>
                  ^
compilation terminated.
[6/939] CC obj/third_party/icu/icui18n/utmscale.o
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

How can I fix?

Comment: You need to look at your links, you've specified a 4 for the link *The v8 guide*, but there is no 4, you have 1 and 2 in your question. Can you please correct them?

Comment: Presumably you need to specify an STL to use. Not sure how to do that in gn, but in ndk-build this would be `APP_STL`.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot

```
android_ndk_major_version=14
```